# Print the variables of js closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

here is my js code

```js
function counter(count){
  function get(){
    return count
  }
  function inc(){
    count++;
  }
  function dec(){
    count--;
  }  
  return {dec,inc}
}
const the_counter=counter(10)
the_counter.inc()
console.log(the_counter)
```

my question is: how do I printout the variables of closure without changing the closure code. I tried console.log, but is does not printout the value of count

Comment: Unless you expose them somehow, like `this.count`, they're not something you can reflect on as far as I know. Keep in mind you'll need something that can be stored as a reference, like `get.scope = { count }`.

Comment: You already have a method to get the value. Why are you not using it? - `console.log(the_counter.get())`

Comment: @slebetman that throws error `the_counter.get is not a function` can I ask why?

Comment: @slebetman  regarding the get function - i am looking for some generic way to dump all of the closure variable without having to write anything to achieve that.

Comment: @GrafiCode the get function is written in the function but is not exposed in the return {dec,inc}

Comment: It is named `closure` for a reason, you cannot get it's internal variables unless you explicitly expose them in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access the variables of closure without changing the closure code?

This is impossible. Closed-over variables are private.

> I am looking for some generic way to dump all of the closure variable without having to write anything to achieve that.

There is none. At least not for accessing the variable and passing it to `console.log` to print it.

However, the object your code did log can be inspected in the console (or in the debugger) and you can navigate to the closure scope:

[image: Chromium devtools screenshot]

Comment: i wonder how debugger has access to that information, maybe i should do the same?

Comment: The debugger uses the debugging protocol to connect to the engine and inspect its internals. No, you cannot do the same from within the code.